# Fixed view header in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, drawerlayout

i want to create a DrawerLayout menu like GooglePlay app. It has two visual components:

- fixed user photo on top
- scrollable list of menu items

[image]

In DrawerLayout i only can declare a ListView, so i'm not able to put fixed header in drawer.

Can you help me, please?

Please look at attachment.

Comment: What does your layout file look like?

Comment: I don't understand your request: i want to create a drawerlayout like google play drawerlayout, with a fixed element on top followed list with scroll. Any idea?

Comment: I m looking for the solution on this on too, If you found any solution please share